# SSP discrepances compared to Admanger - Only in refreshed ads

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

I've implemented a Prebid auction integrated to admanager with refresh adv after 30seconds using the official function listed here:

https://docs.prebid.org/dev-docs/examples/adunit-refresh.html

Here the code used:

CONFIG

```
  pbjs.setConfig({
        debug: PREBID_DEBUG,
        enableSendAllBids: true,
        useBidCache: true,
        bidderTimeout: BIDDER_TIMEOUT,
        consentManagement: iabConfig,
    });
```

The refresing code:

```
function refreshBid(slot,adUnit){
    console.log("refreshBid auction");
    pbjs.que.push(function() {
        pbjs.requestBids({
            timeout: BIDDER_TIMEOUT,
            adUnitCodes: [slot],
            bidsBackHandler: function() {
                pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync([slot]);
                googletag.pubads().refresh([adUnit]);
            }
        });
    });
}

function refreshADV(){
    console.log("refresh adv...");
    var slots=[];
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.pubads().getSlots().forEach(function(e){
            if(e.getAdUnitPath().includes("FloorAd") || e.getAdUnitPath().includes("Sticky")){
                console.log(e.getSlotElementId());
                //Refresh bid...
                refreshBid(e.getSlotElementId(), e); // slot,adUnit
            }
        });
    });
}
setInterval(function(){ refreshADV(); }, 30000);//30ec
```

The refresh is applied only in 2 adv (Floor and Sticky ) and i see the refresh on screen.

We see this discrepancies on numbers (only on those refreshing position):

- AdForm: we see on admanager 522 impression ed € 0,31 - 217 impression
  ed € 0,13  in SSP
- AppNexus: we see on admanager 2.876 impression ed € 0,39  - 231
  impression ed € 0,06  in SSP

the auction restart correctly after 30 sec (i see this on console debug).

any advice for us?

Comment: do you use the lazyloading function somewhere on your ad integration ?

Comment: No, not yet....

Comment: did you try these ? https://docs.prebid.org/dev-docs/common-issues.html